# Why there is an error when I want to check expected result after some time in Jasmine&Karma in Angular?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I want to test this component

```
describe('Test for check if window dissapeard', () => {
    let component: DismissMockedComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DismissMockedComponent>;
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DismissMockedComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });
  
    it('Check if window dissapeard after dissmiss time', () => {
      let delayTime = 3000;
      spyOn(component, "onAfterDelayTime");
  
      component.dismissible = true;
      component.dismissTimer = delayTime;
      fixture.detectChanges();
  
      setTimeout(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.onAfterDelayTime).toHaveBeenCalled();
      }, delayTime); 
    });
  });
```

and very simple mocked component

```
  @Component({
    template: '<my-inform-window (afterDelayTime)="onAfterDelayTime()"></my-inform-window>'
  })
  class DismissMockedComponent {
    delayTime: number;

    onAfterDelayTime(){
        console.log('this function was triggered after delay time')
    }
  }
```

I get an error that

```
Async function did not complete within 5000ms
```

I will add that when I set dismissTime to 1000ms or 2000ms all works correct...

Any idea where problem can be?

Comment: It is bad practice to delay test execution, if you have many such test cases your tests may take minutes or in big code bases even hours to complete. Instead, you can wrap the test case execution function with [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.dev/api/core/testing/fakeAsync?tab=description) and fake the delay with [`tick`](https://angular.dev/api/core/testing/tick?tab=description) without any notable delays in execution, see this [example](https://angular.dev/api/core/testing/tick?tab=usage-notes)

Answer (score 0):

Use [FakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) to test time delayed functioanlities

```
  it('Check if window disappeared after dismiss time', fakeAsync(() => {
    const delayTime = 3000;
    spyOn(component, "onAfterDelayTime");

    component.dismissible = true;
    component.dismissTimer = delayTime;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    tick(delayTime); // Simulate the passage of delayTime milliseconds

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.onAfterDelayTime).toHaveBeenCalled();

    flush(); // Ensure that no more tasks are left in the queue
  }));
```